# Apply a function to multiple datasets using lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, dataset, lapply

I have a large number of datasets for which I want to create the same variable. I would like to create a function to avoid having to repeat the same code many times.

I tried the code below: the first 3 lines describe the creation of the variable that I am trying to apply through the function created below.

```
data1 <- data1 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(new_var = sum(score))


list_data <- c(data1, data2, data3)
my_func <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(new_var = sum(score))
}

lapply(list_data, my_func)
```

I obtain the error message

> no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class
>   "character".

Could you please help me figure this out?

Comment: Your function is not using the argument `x`

Comment: In addition, you are missing a pipse symbol ( `%>%`) after `group_by()`

Comment: Also, I think using `c(` concatenates all your data instead of making a list of your data structures. Try using `list_data <- list(data1, data2, data3)` instead.

Comment: My bad those were all typos, I did run the edited version of the code. @RomainB. I did try that but it did not change the result.

Comment: @unisateur It depends on your data structures, but if you specifically want a *list* of any objects, using `list` is safer as it will always behave that way. To give an example, if data1, 2 and 3 were dataframes, then the `c(` function will make a big list with all their columns, not a list of 3 dataframes like `list` does.

Comment: @RomainB. Yes thank you that makes sense and ```list``` is definitely better for my data structure. Yet I still get the same error message, would you happen to know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me this works fine:

```
my_func <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(new_var = sum(score))
}
data1 <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 3), score = 1:9)
data2 <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 3), score = 11:19)
data3 <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 3), score = 21:29)


list_data <- list(data1, data2, data3)
lapply(list_data, my_func)
```